# Visualizing dependencies for computed fields in Knockout

Tags: dependencies, knockout.js

Is there a way in knockout.js to determine

- which values (`ko.observable` or `ko.computed`) depend on each other in what way (precedents/dependents) and
- which HTML nodes (text binding, for starters) depend on the current value<sup>1</sup>, so I can highlight them on screen.

?

<sup>1</sup> *This implies that I need a way to go from an HTML node to the connected `ko.subscribable`, not just to the view model, like `ko.dataFor()` does. This seems to be impossible as well.*

---

I've built a web application that works like a spreadsheet - many numeric values that are based on each other according to a set of business rules. Some of them are calculated, some of them user-provided.

At the moment I'm using my own JS library that does all the dependency tracking and dynamic screen-updating. This works, but I'd like to swap it with knockout.js for added versatility and elegance.

**Knockout keeps track of this information somewhere. How can I use it?**

---

For example, imagine a spreadsheet (an HTML table) that sums up a few integers:

```
  | A  B  C
--+---------
1 | 4  1  5
2 |    2
3 |    3  8
```

- When the user clicks on cell B3, I'd like to find out that it depends on B1 and B2 and that C3 depends on it.
- When the user clicks on cell C3, I'd like to find out that it depends on A1, B1, C1, B2 and B3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have written a [plugin for Knockout](https://github.com/mbest/knockout-deferred-updates) (2.0+) whose primary purpose is eliminating duplicate updates for computed observables. But since the plugin replaces the `ko.computed` object, I have also added the ability to get a list of the dependencies/dependents for observables. Each computed object has a `getDependencies` method that returns an array of observables, and each observable/computed observable has a `getDependents` method that returns an array of computed observables.

Comment: This looks pretty promising. I suppose it would be easy enough to augment it so it tracks precedents as well. Now I'm thinking about a custom `text` binding that automatically registers the connected HTML elements so I have a chance to call `getDependents` in a click handler, for example.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "precedents".

Comment: Excel terminology: "Dependents: values that depend on the current value." "Precedents: values that the current value depends on."

Comment: Okay. I've just called them "dependencies".

Comment: Yes, but in your code they're going just into one direction. I will try to base a plug-in on your code that tracks both directions. Could take me a while, though. Anyway. I accept your answer, since its clear that knockout must be modified to do what I have in mind and your code shows how to do it.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding you, but I'm quite sure that my code does give you both directions. `getDependents` will give you the dependents of an observable and `getDependencies` will give you its precedents.

Comment: Ah, you're right! I'm sorry, my bad. Looks like connecting HTML nodes and subscribables is the only thing left for me to do, then.

Answer (score 4):

This is a very interesting question - and, it seems, not a simple one to answer. I've looked at the knockout source and it looks like this data is stored in the `_subscriptionsToDependencies` property, but that doesn't seem to publicly exposed.

I did notice `getDependenciesCount` which is exposed - check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2kcuH/) to see it in action.

I'm still investigating this, but it seems like it may require a fork of knockout itself unless we can get at the underlying observable. But here's what I've found so far, which you may find helpful:

Running it through the debugger, it seems like at runtime the minified version of knockout renames the `_subscriptionsToDependencies` property to `V`. At runtime the `getDependenciesCount` property's value is : `function (){return v.length}`

I hope this helps.

Edit: For those who arrive to this question looking for the answer, it does not seem to be possible in KnockoutJS as of version 2.1

Comment: Usually I answer the simple questions myself. ;) -- Knowing the dependencies count is close but no cigar. Also, this tells me nothing about the precedents. The question "which HTML element displays this value" has occurred to me at a different occasion in the past as well. This seems equally difficult to answer.